# Focus and click on non form elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wanted to have a tab index on non-form elements ex: div tag
for that, I used tab index but when my div focussed and enter button tapped its not trigging ng-click which div tag has

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button"
     ng-click="!user.Active || selectUser(user)"
     class="multi-user no-outline"
     ng-repeat="user in Users" >
    <div class="bold text-capitalize text-primary" ng-bind="user.Name"></div>
    <small class="text-capitalize" ng-bind="user.RoleName"></small>
    <label class="label rel-label"
           ng-if="user.Active !== true">
      Deactive
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do AngularJS, but pressing Enter doesn't generate a click (except on radio buttons and checkboxes), it generates `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` events. You probably want [`ng-keypress`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress). You'll need to check `$event`'s [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) (or [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for older browsers) to see if it was Enter that was pressed.